# Add pagination to blog

Tags: templates, pagination, blog

I want to limit 3 blog entry snippets per page and include pagination for additional pages.  Here's what I have so far, but pagination isn't working.

```
            <div id="page-content">

<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' =>3, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
    <div>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a><br />
        <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author(); ?></small>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br />
    </div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
      </div>

<?php posts_nav_link( $sep, $prelabel, $nextlabel ); ?> 
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php posts_nav_link('','','&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php posts_nav_link('','Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
</div>
        <!--#page-content-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sweet and short of this, don't use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) if you need paginated queries. `get_posts` works perfectly if you are going to use a custom query that doesn't need pagination, but it really becomes a big complicated mess when you need to introduce pagination.

I think the easiest and most appropriate here is to make use of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to construct your custom query, that is, **if you can't use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query** to get your desired output from the main query.

Also, these two lines are unnecessary, you must delete these

```
<?php posts_nav_link( $sep, $prelabel, $nextlabel ); ?> 
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

I do think that [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [`previous_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) is better to use with a custom query, ie with `WP_Query`. You must just remember however to set the `$max_pages` parameter when you make use of a custom query, otherwise your pagination will break

With a few minor tweaks, your query should look like this

```
<div id="page-content">

    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' =>3, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'paged' => $paged );
    $postslist = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); ?>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a><br />
                <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author(); ?></small>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br />
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous Entries', $postslist->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next Entries &raquo;' ); ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>

</div>
```